# chpasswd and openssl

Tags: users, openssl, hashsum, passwd

I'm trying to pass an MD5 password to chpasswd but it doesn't seem to work.

```
echo username:$(openssl passwd -1 -salt salt password)
```

Then I try to pass this to `chpasswd` to change the password

```
echo 'username:$1$salt$aldkjflsfj' | /usr/sbin/chpasswd -e
```

However, when I do this the password change does not seem to take effect -- `/etc/shadow` is updated but if I try to use the password it does not work.

This does work:

```
echo username:password | /usr/sbin/chpasswd
```

`passwd` also works

More info:

```
$ S=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 5 | head -n 1)
$ echo username:$(openssl passwd -1 -salt "$S" password)
 username:$1$nPkvS$eKljAIRsFLXOffXti.ZtO/
$ echo 'username:$1$nPkvS$eKljAIRsFLXOffXti.ZtO/' | chpasswd -e
$  grep username /etc/shadow
username:$1$nPkvS$eKljAIRsFLXOffXti.ZtO/:16722:0:99999:7:::
```

Comment: Tried here using `echo foo:$(openssl passwd -1 -salt salt password) | chpasswd -e` and worked fine when I then tried to logon as foo.  Worth posting the shadow entry before and after ?

Comment: @steve When I do it in one shot like that it works, but if I do it in the steps shown above it does not. What's the difference?

Comment: @chaos look at the more info part, it is quoted.

Comment: Yeah I see, it needs double quotes on openssl hash generation.If you write up the answer I'll accept it.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments must be quoted, else the shell validates [special characters](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/special-chars.html) inside those arguments:

```
echo "username:"$(openssl passwd -1 -salt "$salt" "$password")
```

Use double quote here, that the shell evaluates the variables.

Now, the `echo` command must be quoted too:

```
echo 'username:$1$salt$aldkjflsfj' | ...
```

Use single quotes here, because the $-signs are part of the entry and must persist.

---

**Warning**: I don't recommend to change password like this. Those commands, and therefore the plain passwords, can be seen in the listings of `ps` and `top` for example. `openssl` has a mechanism for such cases, to read the password from a file.